# How to change the diff tool used by VSCode for git?

Tags: visual-studio-code, diff

I would like to use the [difftastic](https://github.com/Wilfred/difftastic) diff tool, which ignores whitespace changes in code (amongst other useful functionalities), and I have set my `.gitconfig` to use `difft` (the binary file of difftastic) as my preferred external diff tool using this command:

```
git config --global diff.external difft
```

And, my `.gitconfig` has these lines in it:

```
[diff]
    external = difft
```

However, the VSCode text editor still shows whitespace diffs. I have searched for a way to change the diff tool in VSCode to no avail, the only results are "How to set VSCode as the default merge/diff tool for git".

To clarify, I would like to change the diff tool used by [the vscode text editor section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpZOr.png) as well as the diff viewer. I do not want to change the tool used by the commandline `git` command itself. In the image I've linked, it shows changes for whitespace, which should not be happening if `difft` is set as the diff tool.

Comment: type a `git diff` command in the terminal

Comment: @rioV8 running the command still doesn't change the diff tool for vscode

Comment: where have you read that you can change the diff tool of VSC when you click on the SCM bar

Comment: Q: Your question is *NOT* about Git diff, and *NOT* about VSCode/Git integration.  Your question is *ONLY* about customizing the "diff" functionality in the *VSCode editor*.  Correct?  Remember: "the diff tool for VSCode" *IS* the VSCode editor.  Or a plugin, like [Partial Diff](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryu1kn.partial-diff).

Comment: Be warned that difft, while excellent, is really slow. I don't advise making it replace the default diff

Comment: @paulsm4 Correct. I only want to customize the diff functionality in the VSCode editor. I didn't know how to frame my question to ask that unambiguously.

Comment: @rioV8 I don't understand your second reply. What do you mean?

Comment: you want to change the diff tool, where have you got the idea that it IS possible

Comment: @rioV8 I didn't know whether it was possible to do so or not, I asked here because I didn't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can change the tool Git uses to "diff" two files: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool (this is Git functionality - it has nothing directly to do with VSCode).
- You can substitute a custom editor for the built-in the Visual Studio code editor: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors.
- You can add a custom "diff" plugin to Visual Studio, for example, "Partial Diff": https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryu1kn.partial-diff.
- What you *CANNOT* do is swap in a custom app to change the "diff" functionality of the default VSCode editor.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Code does not use an external utility to compute the diff. The necessary algorithms are [directly implemented](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/2b1ef23/src/vs/editor/common/diff/algorithms) in VS Code and you don't have any control over them.

Using an arbitrary external utility would most likely not result in a good user experience either. If VS Code cannot understand the generated diff, it would not be able to display the output with the diff editor and you would lose features like syntax highlighting.

However, I may have an alternative solution to your original problem (using difftastic in VS Code). I am currently working on my own extension that adds a semantic diff mode to VS Code. It supports fewer languages than difftastic, but has additional features like moved code detection:

[image: Moved code in SemanticDiff]

If that is what you are looking for, you can find the extension (SemanticDiff) in the Visual Studio Code [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=semanticdiff.semanticdiff).